# Output Log10 Plot in rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to plot the log10 of my data using rpy2 but I get an error that 'log10' is not defined.

I have read in a table like this:

```
f = r("read.table('RandomDistribution.tsv',sep='\t')")
```

then I am plotting like this:

```
r.hist(f[0], breaks=100, main = '5 Reads', xlab='Variant Freq', ylab='# Vars')
```

which works fine, but when I try to log transform and then plot, I get an error.

```
r.hist(log10(f[0]), breaks=100, main = '5 Reads', xlab='Variant Freq', ylab='# Vars')
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: `NameError: name 'log10' is not defined`

Comment: It looks to me like you're calling R from within python, with some sort of member function `.` syntax. How about `r.hist(r.log10(f[0]) ...)`